# building a solution from makefile VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, makefile

I just downloaded some source code to which it states that a Visual studion .sln file can be made by using makefile. There is a makefile file in the folder. Any suggestions on how I could get started on creating a sln from makefile ?

Comment: most likely you need [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) to create .sln from make file.

Comment: Use the Visual C++ -> General -> Makefile Project template.  I don't think it is available in the Express edition.

Answer (score 0):

Cmake! http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/runningcmake.html

It will need the vs-compiler, so be sure to start it via the visual studio console (it's just for simplifying the path configuration).
Cmake also comes with a nice GUI.